# Return Back To Parent View-UINavigation Controller

Tags: iphone

I have a page with navigation controller, when i click a login button, my view changed to login view(sub view),
My question is how i return back to my parent view when a button click in the ogin view(sub view)

Thanks,
Companion

Answer (score 0):

If your login view is just a simple view you should be able to go back by removing it from its superview:

```
[loginView removeFromSuperview];
```

but you are implying that you are using modal viewcontrollers...
in that case:

```
[logincontroller.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```